# Join 3 tables in SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, join

I have 3 tables in SQLite database:

**Songs:**

```
_id | name | length | artist_id (foreign key) | album_id (foreign key)
```

**Artists:**

```
_id | name
```

**Albums:**

```
_id | name
```

I need a query (use it in an Android app) of a table that consists of the following columns:

```
_id | name | length | artist_id | artist_name | album_id | album_name
```

However, I write the following query statement:

```
SELECT Songs._id, Songs.name, Songs.length, Songs.artist_id, Artists.name, Songs.album_id, Albums.name FROM Songs, Artists, Albums WHERE Songs.artist_id = Artists._id AND Songs.album_id = Albums._id
```

but it gives me an empty table. I tried `OR` instead of `AND` and it gives incorrect results (every song duplicates in each album, though the artist is correct). How can I fix my query statement to join the 3 tables in a single table?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using an explicit `JOIN` instead of an implicit one, the following should get what you want, although it is curious that your implicit join syntax did not return correct results in the first place.  I have used a `LEFT JOIN`, to account for songs which do not have an associated artist or album, but that may not be necessary for your data set and an `INNER JOIN` could be used instead.

I have also added column aliases to eliminate ambiguity when fetching rows, since you have similar column names in most of your tables (`id, name`).

```
SELECT
  Songs._id AS song_id,
  Songs.name AS song_name, 
  Songs.length, 
  Songs.artist_id AS artist_id, 
  Artists.name AS artist_name, 
  Songs.album_id AS album_id, 
  Albums.name AS album_name
FROM 
 Songs 
 LEFT JOIN Artists ON Songs.artist_id = Artists._id
 LEFT JOIN Albums ON Songs.album_id = Albums._id
```

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. But, he would probably need a `LEFT JOIN` in case a Song doesn't have a tag for an Arist or Album.

Comment: @MadBurn Was just changing that

Comment: Works just great. Much appreciate it. Thanks :)

Comment: I have `group_concat` in my select if i join only 1 table everything works fine but another join mess up whole query records are repeating.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar You probably have a mis-application of `GROUP BY`. You should post it as a different question.

Comment: Yeah you are right this was the group_by thing actually i have find a link with an answer let me try that please i really hope it works. I'm doing group_concat, group by + multiple inner join for the very first time and its already 2 days so you might know my situation :)

Comment: same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537345/how-to-join-more-than-one-tables-using-id-sqlite

Comment: So basically, in order to use column aliases, you have to specify each of those columns no matter how many they are?

Comment: @NiiLaryea As opposed to `SELECT *`?  I would never really recommend using `SELECT *` in production code; I think it's better to be explicit always. But you could alias one table of the join and not the other, saving some typing:  `SELECT songs.id AS song_id, songs.name AS song_name, artist.* FROM...` but then you have to know that the column `id` refers to `artist.id` and `name` is `artist.name`. You cannot provide a "global" alias prefixes for all columns in a table. I've never seen an RDBMS that supports anything like that (though one may exist), and it's not standard SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Try this select, may by the `Artists` is more important than others, so the `Songs` come trough `Artists` and `Albums` from `Songs`.

```
SELECT
  Songs._id AS song_id,
  Songs.name AS song_name, 
  Songs.length, 
  Songs.artist_id AS artist_id, 
  Artists.name AS artist_name, 
  Songs.album_id AS album_id, 
  Albums.name AS album_name
FROM 
 Artists
 LEFT JOIN Songs ON Songs.artist_id = Artists._id
 LEFT JOIN Albums ON Songs.album_id = Albums._id
```

Also if there is no entry in `Songs` belonging to a particular artist or no entry in `Albums` belonging to a particular song, you will still get the artist entry thanks to the `LEFT JOIN`. If you would like to return only artists with songs and albums, use `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try sql inner join

```
           inner join Artists on Songs.artist_id = Artists._id
```